# Identifying a string pattern in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify a column which has a special sort of string in it. For simplicity of the question here is a small sample size of the column I am working with.

[image: pic1]

The column contains names of people, but we see some records have a special key id in the last 7 to 8 digits of the cell. The one I am interested in are the ones that start with an uppercase "C" followed by 6 numeric digits.

I am trying to get results similar to this.

[image: pic2]

Column B (Cab ID) just takes the 7 digits from the right, which is easily done by excel functions in vba. I am trying to get column C (Flag), where I identify whether they are the records that I am interested in, which are the ones which start with an uppercase "C" and are followed by 6 numeric digits. If they are, I mark them down as "Y" else "N".

If any extra details needs to be added, let me know and I will make a quick edit as soon as possible to the question.

Comment: I don't know enough VBA to give a formal answer, but the regex pattern you want to use here is `C\d{6}$`.  This would match the names having the ID at the end (and if it fails, then you just pull over the entire original name).

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Tim Biegeleisen. I will try to do something with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### String Ends in a Substring Followed by a Number of Digits

[image]

**An Improvement Long Over-Due (Roughly 5 Years Later)**

- I got an upvote today (thanks but please use the new code) on the old answer so I thought it was time to correct and improve.

```vb
Sub FlagColumn()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SHEET_ID As Variant = "Sheet1" ' Sheet Name/Index
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "C"
    Const SUBSTRING As String = "C"
    Const SUBSTRING_MATCH_CASE As Boolean = True
    Const NUMBER_OF_DIGITS As Long = 6
    Const FLAG_YES As Variant = "Y"
    Const FLAG_NO As Variant = "N"
    
    ' Read.
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_ID)
    
    ' Declare the variables for the source range and its number of rows.
    Dim srg As Range, rCount As Long
    ' Using a refence to the first cell...
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        ' ... and the 'End' property, calculate the number of rows...
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        ' ... and after establishing that the number of rows is valid (>0)...
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' ... reference the source (single-column) range ('srg').
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Define a variant array ('Data')...
    Dim Data() As Variant
    ' ... and return the values from the source range in it.
    ' The resulting array is a 2D one-based (single-column) array.
    If rCount = 1 Then ' a single cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Build the string pattern...
    Dim Pattern As String: Pattern = SUBSTRING & String(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS, "#")
    If Not SUBSTRING_MATCH_CASE Then Pattern = LCase(Pattern)
    ' ... and acquire its length.
    Dim pLen As String: pLen = Len(Pattern)
    
    ' Modify.
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim rVal As Variant, r As Long, IsMatch As Boolean
    ' Loop through the rows of the array,...
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' ... and after establishing whether each value matches the pattern,...
        rVal = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(rVal) Then
            If Len(rVal) >= pLen Then
                If SUBSTRING_MATCH_CASE Then
                    If Right(rVal, pLen) Like Pattern Then IsMatch = True
                Else
                    If Right(LCase(rVal), pLen) Like Pattern Then IsMatch = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ' ... replace the value in the array with the appropriate flag.
        If IsMatch Then
            IsMatch = False
            Data(r, 1) = FLAG_YES
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = FLAG_NO
        End If
    Next r
            
    ' Write.
            
    ' Reference the destination (single-column) range ('drg')...
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    ' ... and write (copy) the modified values from the array to it.
    drg.Value = Data
            
    ' Inform, to confirm the code has run.
    
    MsgBox "Column flagged.", vbInformation
                
End Sub
```

**A List of Improvements (Corrections)**

- Added more appropriate comments.
- Used more readable constants.
- `cFirst` and `cSourceC` have become a single variable `SRC_FIRST_CELL`.
- `cSearch` has become `SUBSTRING` and can have any reasonable number of characters.
- Added a constant for case-insensitivity (`SUBSTRING_MATCH_CASE`)
- Added a constant to allow any reasonable number of digits (`NUMBER_OF_DIGITS`).
- Added constants for the flags.
- Qualified the worksheet with the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).
- Added a variable for the number of rows (`rCount`).
- Implemented a check for no data (`rCount < 1`).
- Implemented a check whether there is just a single cell with data (when `Data = srg.Value` wouldn't work).
- Implemented checking for cell errors and the length of the cell values to avoid previously possible run-time errors.
- By building a string pattern (`Pattern`), enabled the use of the `Like` operator (could be considered an introduction into `RegEx`) to determine whether there is a match. Using `IsNumeric` isn't such a good idea, especially, by allowing different numbers of digits, it is questionable what could yield in a numeric value (e.g. `True`, `False`, a date, time, a scientific number...).
- ...

### **Bad Initial Answer (Works Until It Doesn't)**

Checks if the first of the last seven chars is capital "C". If so, checks if the last 6 chars are numeric. Only then returns "Y".

```vb
Sub LeftRightArray()

    Const cSheet1 As Variant = "Sheet1"  ' Sheet Name/Index
    Const cFirst As Integer = 2          ' Source First Row
    Const cSourceC As Variant = "A"      ' Source Column
    Const cTargetC As Variant = "B"      ' Target Column
    Const cSearch As String = "C"        ' Search String

    Dim lastR As Long     ' Source Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim vnt As Variant    ' Array
    Dim strCompare        ' Compare String
    
    ' Paste Source Range into Array
    With Worksheets(cSheet1)
        lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cSourceC).End(xlUp).Row
        vnt = .Range(.Cells(cFirst, cSourceC), .Cells(lastR, cSourceC))
    End With
        
    ' Change data in Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vnt)
        ' Check if C is the first char of last 7 chars.
        If Left(Right(vnt(i, 1), 7), 1) = cSearch Then
            ' Check if last 6 chars are numeric.
            If IsNumeric(Right(vnt(i, 1), 6)) Then
                vnt(i, 1) = "Y"
              Else
                vnt(i, 1) = "N"
            End If
          Else ' C is not the first letter of last 7 chars.
            vnt(i, 1) = "N"
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Paste Array into Target Range
    With Worksheets(cSheet1).Cells(cFirst, cTargetC)
        .Resize(UBound(vnt), UBound(vnt, 2)) = vnt
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this answer works for me. For example, what if I had someones name which starts with the "C" and has 6 characters after it. This would flag it as "Y".

Comment: @DSM: Sure, will come up with something soon.

Comment: I am getting an error message, "Type mismatched" on this line `If Not IsNumeric(CInt(Mid(strCompare, j, 1))) Then Exit For`. Is this method checking each and every digit after "C", so its looping 6 times every row for each digit? Would this be slow if I were to do this with data size of 40,000 rows?

Comment: @It wouldn't be slow, it was half a second for 65000 rows, but I've reduced it now to just check if all the 6 chars are numeric.

Comment: works just fine now! Thank you. Could I know why you thought of looping through the 6 digits to check it 1 by 1? Is there any special reason behind it?

Comment: @I've recently seen some code where it was needed. I guess I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula in column `C`:
`=IFERROR(IF(AND(MID(A2,FIND("*",A2)+1,1)="C",LEN(A2)-(FIND("*",A2)+1)=6),"Y","N"),"N")`

**Alternative:**
Put this formula in column `B`
`=IFERROR(IF(AND(MID(A2,FIND("*",A2)+1,1)="C",LEN(A2)-(FIND("*",A2)+1)=6),MID(A2,FIND("*",A2)+1,7),""),"")`

and this formula in column`C`
`=IF(LEN(B2)<>0,"Y","N")`

Comment: Oh, nice way to make use of the asterisk in the string.

Comment: I updated the answer for the case when you don't have a 6 number of digits after "C" char

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the below excel formula as well. This formula can be used in VBA code after little modification.

`=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2))=0,"N",IF(EXACT(LEFT(B2,1),"C"),"Y","N"))`

Note: A2 is the cell which contains your data, example: Joe*C5464647. Please refer snapshot.

[Excel Snapshot with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T64a.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this only considers numerical values in the cells. So, for example, Janice*GH092123 would be flagged "Y" as well.

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the answer. Had not seen the requirement of only matching the capital C